# Spacetime curvature replaces acceleration?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, acceleration, curvature

In my understanding, not only mass but any kind of energy/ force bends spacetime. So is it correct to say that every object in the world moves along geodesic? If the object is submit to a force, it will not feel an acceleration: the force will bend the underlying spacetime --> the geodesic of the object will change --> its worldline in spacetime will change, but only because the curvature of spacetime has changed. It will still move along a geodesic. So acceleration, in some sense, simply doesn't exist anymore.

Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: I'm sure this has already been answered somewhere on Physics SE, but I don't know where, so I'll post a quick hint: Worldlines that are geodesics describe free-fall; an observer following such a worldline feels weightless. Worldlines that are not geodesics describe deviations from free-fall, and such an observer feels weight.

Comment: @Chiral Yes but my question is how a worldline cannot be a geodesic? If there is any force, it will simply change the curvature and so the geodesic path of the particle will change as well. But it will still be a geodesic curve. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Federico, when I read *"its worldline in spacetime will change, but only because the curvature of spacetime has changed"*,  the impression I get is that you haven't conceptualized spacetime correctly. Reading *"It will still move along a geodesic"* strengthens that impression. Are you picturing an object as *moving* in spacetime?

Comment: @alfred Yes I am. Is this wrong? Isn't a worldline traced by the motion of a particle through spacetime?

Comment: Federio, if you're thinking of a point particle as point moving on a worldline in spacetime, then yes, I believe this is wrong. For example, see [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/133821/9887) from Ben Crowell: *"Objects don't move through spacetime. Objects move through space. If you depict an object in spacetime, you have a world-line. The world-line doesn't move through spacetime, it simply extends across spacetime."*  - In other words, the depiction of a point particle in spacetime is *not* as a point but, rather, a curve in spacetime

Answer (score 4):

Not *every* force is manifested through the curvature of spacetime, only gravity. Take the electromagnetic field, for example. It has energy-momentum density, so it affects the gravitational field and hence the movement of particles. But this is not the only effect it has: on a charged particle, it also acts directly through the electromagnetic force.

Mathematically, for a particle of mass $m$ and charge $q$ in an EM field $F_{\mu\nu}$, the geodesic equation is modified to

$$\frac{d u^\mu}{d\tau} + \Gamma^\mu{}_{\nu\lambda} u^\nu u^\lambda = \frac{q}{m} F^\mu{}_\nu u^\nu.$$

If there was no electromagnetic field, the right hand side would be zero, and you would just have the geodesic equation with the gravitational field $\Gamma^\mu{}_{\nu\lambda}$. If there is an EM field, then two things happen. For one, its energy-momentum influences the gravitational field, so that $\Gamma^\mu{}_{\nu\lambda}$ changes. But it also directly applies a force on the particle, given by the right hand side of the equation, and this effect is usually much bigger. The particle doesn't follow a geodesic anymore.