# In general relativity, what makes an object released in a gravitational field START to fall?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity

I understand why a released object moves as it does once it has started moving, and why all objects fall at the same speed, removing other effects. But I don't see why the curvature of space would make it start to move in the first place, thank you.

Comment: Can you give some details on your first statement: what makes you think that a released object moves as it does once it has started moving?

Comment: Have you looked up *geodesic deviation*? If not, I would start there.

Comment: Hint: it's the curvature of *spacetime*, not just space.

Comment: It’s moving through spacetime even before it’s released.

Comment: @G.Smith, that whole "moving through spacetime" thing can get some feathers here ruffled. I was thinking of [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/133821/9887) but heck, when did Ben Crowell leave PSE?

Comment: Looked up geodesic deviation, it's about objects already in motion.:                   "geodesic deviation describes the tendency of objects to approach or recede from one another while moving under the influence of a spatially varying gravitational field.    If two objects are set in motion along two initially parallel trajectories, the presence of a tidal gravitational force will cause the trajectories to bend towards or away from each other..."                 I'm wondering why the shape of the space can make an object stationary in relation to the mass it is near start moving.

Comment: I was asked about why an object already in motion moves as it does, that is explained in GR via geodesic paths through the field.

Comment: @David To be in (inertial) motion or to be static is the same, even in classical mechanics. Two objects carefully placed to freely float in the space station can be initially stationary for the crew and moving for an approaching ship.

Comment: I think the crucial misunderstanding is in the  word "released". It implies  a force in Newtonian mechanics, that keeps the object motionless,  and boundary conditions in relativistic..

Answer (score 0):

In the weak field limit (which applies near a planet) curvature of space is so small that its effect can be ignored completely; gravity is explained by looking only at time. We know that clocks on GPS satellites do not keep time with identical clocks on Earth, and we also know that energy is the time component of a 4-vector. It follows that energy is changed when an object moves up or down. We measure the energy change directly, as light is redshifted when it goes upwards, and we can calculate that the change is equivalent to potential energy in Newtonian gravity. The apparent force of gravity is minus the gradient of potential energy, so that the apparent change in the rate of clocks with height is directly responsible for the apparent force of gravity.

Comment: It has been proved via the Rietdijk-Putnam argument that Minkowski spacetime means no motion through time. It is out of the question to explain this via 'moving through spacetime'. And gravitational time dilation is merely a pattern in the block of block time, it cannot be used to explain why an object starts moving.

Comment: @David, this website is about mainstream physics, not the misunderstandings of individuals.

Comment: @David, the answer concerns general relativity, not Minkowski spacetime

Comment: Because general relativity uses Minkowski spacetime, and depends on it, there's a need to explain things in a way that is consistent with Minkowski spacetime. I'm still unsure about the question, but thanks for your help.

Comment: General relativity uses *local* Minkowski spacetime. The explanation is fully consistent. You cite theories which are not

Comment: The Rietdijk-Putnam argument shows that depending on Minkowski spacetime, as GR does, motion through time does not exist in any form, except as a perception-based illusion. Local or not makes no difference. Whether an event is past or future is frame dependent, so motion along the time axis cannot have enough existence to cause an object to start falling. There must be a better explanation from GR that trying to use motion through time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108379/discussion-between-charles-francis-and-david).